# Use a link_to to set persistent cookie in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, button, link-to

I would like to save a cookie with a visitor's browser using a link_to or a button. It's sole purpose is display a one time welcome message.

application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :first_time_visiting?
  def first_time_visiting?
    if session[:first_time].nil?
      # session[:first_time] = 1
      redirect_to "pages#welcome"
    end
  end
end
```

Instead of automatically accepting the cookie like the commented code, I'd like to attach `session[:first_time] = 1` to a link_to or a button_to in the pages#welcome view. I'm sure this is a simple task but I'm just wondering if I'm going about this correctly. Can I just use something like:

Pages#welcome:

```
<%= link_to("Continue", :controller => "home", :action => "index", :first_time => 1) %>
```

Thank you for reading my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/fyprk/rails_beginner_needing_help_with_setting_a_cookie/

A kind redditor answered my question.